# Transient analysis with differential equation

Tags: differential, transient

Anyone may help with the differential equation for vC?

[image]

I write the Nodal analysis equations and find equation for vC but roots of characteristic equation is incorrect! v1 – the node where current source enters the top of schema

[image]

Comment: The solution is already given on the image... What do you need actually? You only have to do the maths...

Comment: At first look the solution is shown previously but there is one mistake in it that I may not found - the result characteristic equation must be as in the next post!

Answer (score 1):

Kirchoff's voltage law: $$\large 20\int (3-i)dt+10(3-i)=4i+ 2\large\frac{di}{dt}$$

Differentiating: $$\large 60-20i-10\large\frac{di}{dt}=4\frac{di}{dt}+2\frac{d^2i}{dt^2}$$

Homogeneous equation is: $$\large p^2 + 7p + 10=0$$

Comment: Thanks, when I use pure KVL and KCL I get equal characteristic equation, but when I'm using nodal analysis I do some magic mistake and can't get characteristic equation that you wrote. It's known that there is no difference what method of analysis to use (KVL, KCL, nodal, mesh current) the result must be same! May you help me to check error in my calculus?

Comment: You need to fill in the gaps in your analysis to find the error.

Comment: May you include some details? I can't understand about what you are talking. My vC equation - second row in matrix - don't have vC summand to achieve p^2 +7*p + 10 = 0 characteristic equation. Maybe some fact was lost in my nodal equations?

Comment: What books about circuit analysis may you recommend?

Comment: The matrix equations look ok, so show your steps to the characteristic equation

Comment: The upper MathCAD screenshot have been updated. “p” is equal to duC/dt, p^2 is equal to d^2uC/dt^2

Comment: uC - is same as "v"

Comment: The solution was founded. The “vC” part of result differential equation was lost!
I wrote:
3*R2 + vL – R1*iC – R2*iC = 0
But it must be:
3*R2 + vL – R1*iC – R2*iC = vC
Then I can get the proper characteristic equation.

Comment: May you also look that post?
http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275780/nodal-analysis-with-laplace-of-simple-circuit
Same schema but with Laplace method!