# KCL and KVL with Laplace incorrect result

Tags: analysis, laplace-transform, transient

For t > 0 find v0(t)

[image]

Using nodal analysis I was found v1 and v2, take difference and find correct result

But I can’t make same with direct KCL, KVL approach

[image]

May anyone help with that?

Comment: That was fixed but result still incorrect

Comment: Is \$8(e^{-t}-e^{-6t})\$ incorrect?

Comment: That is correct! But my in MathCAD "v0(s) invlaplace -> ..." is not equal to your calculations, but why?

Comment: Ask MathCAD!!!!!

Comment: Are you find result handy?

Comment: I don't understand the question. But you can easily work out the result from the final LT equation. Your brain is obviously better than Mathcad.

Comment: What soft do use use? Or use write equations on paper?

Comment: I only use software as a last resort

Comment: May you also look that post: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/275780/nodal-analysis-with-laplace-of-simple-circuit

Comment: You do not appear to acknowledge helpful answers by upvoting etc. That is the usual courtesy. We don't get paid here.

Comment: Thanks a lost for your tips and help! They are very useful! There is no vote because the forum doesn’t allow voting the users with low reputation (i. e. me). And I see in answer rules that don’t need to write any thanks and other equal comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation for \$V_o(s)\$ may be factorised to:
$$\frac{40}{(s+1)(s+6)}=\frac{8}{s+1}-\frac{8}{s+6}$$

Giving:
$$v_o(t)=8(e^{-t}-e^{-6t})$$

The MathCAD answer is also correct (expand it by hand to see), but not in as compact/useful a form.